# small string optimization for vector?

Tags: c++, string, stl, vector

I know several (all?) STL implementations implement a "small string" optimization where instead of storing the usual 3 pointers for begin, end and capacity a string will store the actual character data in the memory used for the pointers if sizeof(characters) <= sizeof(pointers). I am in a situation where I have lots of small vectors with an element size <= sizeof(pointer). I cannot use fixed size arrays, since the vectors need to be able to resize dynamically and may potentially grow quite large. However, the median (not mean) size of the vectors will only be 4-12 bytes. So a "small string" optimization adapted to vectors would be quite useful to me. Does such a thing exist?

I'm thinking about rolling my own by simply brute force converting a vector to a string, i.e. providing a vector interface to a string. Good idea?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Further, what do you mean by a `vector` interface to a `string`? Are you talking about a special `svector` class to hold small strings?

Comment: No. I mean a string holding arbitrary values instead of char types - just like a vector. A vector interface to a string means wrapping the string object and exposing a vector compatible interface, adding the missing functions like push_back.

Comment: Wouldn't it rather be possible to do something with the allocator? You wouldn't get even 3 pointers worth of memory, since the vector also needs a way to know if it is in the "small" or "large" mode.

Comment: The only standard library implementation that performs the "space optimization" you're referring to is Dinkumware's standard library, which is the library that ships with Microsoft's Visual Studio.

Comment: I never tried but if one does `template<class T> using small_vector = std::basic_string<T>;` could one get something very close to a small vector optimization? (it shoudl work for pod classes as least).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can borrow the [SmallVector](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#dss_smallvector) implementation from LLVM. (header only, located in LLVM\include\llvm\ADT)

Comment: It's not header-only anymore.

Comment: header is here:
https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/include/llvm/ADT/SmallVector.h

Answer (score 28):

Boost 1.58 was just released and it's `Container` library has a [small_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.small_vector) class based on the LLVM `SmallVector`.

There is also a `static_vector` which cannot grow beyond the initially given size. Both containers are header-only.

facebook's [folly](https://github.com/facebook/folly) library also has some awesome containers.

It has a [`small_vector`](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/small_vector.md) which can be configured with a template parameter to act like boost's `static` or `small` vectors. It can also be configured to use small integer types for it's internal size bookkeeping which given that they are facebook is no surprise :)

There is work in progress to make the library cross platform so Windows/MSVC support should land some day...

Answer (score 4):

It was [discussed](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/browse_frm/thread/c46842f95539442b/d8cf49a1c9e06c12#d8cf49a1c9e06c12) years ago (and a few of the names in that thread may look a bit familiar :-) ), but I don't know of an existing implementation. I don't think I'd try to adapt `std::string` to the task. The exact requirements on the type over which `std::basic_string` aren't well stated, but the standard is pretty clear that it's only intended for something that acts a lot like `char`. For types that are substantially different, it might still work, but it's hard to say what would happen -- it was never intended for, and probably hasn't been tested with many types other than small integers.

A fully conforming implementation of `std::vector` is a lot of work. But implementing a usable subset of `std::vector` from scratch (even including a small vector optimization) won't usually be terribly difficult. If you include a small vector optimization, I'm reasonably certain you can't meet all the requirements on `std::vector` though.

In particular, swapping or moving a vector where you've stored actual data in the vector object means you'll need to swap/move actual data items, where the requirements on `std::vector` are predicated on its storing only a pointer to the data, so it can normally<sup>1</sup> swap or move the contents just by manipulating the pointers, without actually touching the data items themselves at all. As such, it's required to be able to do these things without throwing, even if manipulating the data items themselves would/will throw. As such, a small vector optimization will preclude meeting those requirements.

On the other hand, as noted above, one of the requirements on `std::string` is that it can only store items that can be manipulated without throwing. As such, if `std::string` is a viable option at all, implementing your own `vector`-like container probably won't need to worry about those details a lot either.

---

1. There is one case where you end up having to swap/move actual data items, even in an actual `std::vector`: if the two vectors use different allocators, then you have to allocate space for the objects in the destination via that vector's allocator.

Comment: Implementing `std::vector` *correctly* from scratch is surprisingly hard. Of course, if you choose to ignore exception safety it becomes a lot easier, but then it's no longer a meaningful (or useful) `vector` implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - unfortunately the discussion never really reached a conclusion.

Implementing my own vector wouldn't be all that difficult, I agree. However, I was hoping of just plugging in some ready made class and see the effect on memory consumption. I'm currently toying with various ideas of reducing our memory footprint and this is only one of them.

Comment: When that is said, I do think a custom vector implementation would be the best way to achieve this. Wrapping the existing vector class would make it hard to exploit the object's size efficiently, and a custom vector isn't rocket science, as long as you're careful and know what you're doing.

Comment: @jalf: it's certainly true that it isn't trivial -- and there's one requirement that probably *can't* be met. Swapping two vectors isn't allowed to throw an exception except if the copy ctor for the allocator throws, even if T(T const&) and/or swap(T, T) throws. I don't see any way to meet that requirement using a built-in buffer.

Comment: @Jerry: True, I don't think that can be done either. But at least it's a bit of a corner case, where you can probably live without the nothrow guarantee.

Comment: one of the hardest part about a vector is choosing the strategy for expanding the internal array

Comment: @jalf: re: object size: couldn't you wrap a std::vector inside of a union with a std::array<T, number of shortvector elements> ? That way you can use the methods of the containers and "only" think of transition from one to the other.

Answer (score 2):

If T is a POD type why not basic_string instead of vector??

Comment: Note that you'd have to write a `std::char_traits` specialization (or an equivalent traits class) for the POD type. The requirements aren't all that severe, other than the need to nominate a special `eof` value, but I expect it's kind of tedious.

Comment: Moreover, there is no guarantee that `basic_string<MyPodType>` will use small string optimization, and no portable way of specifying how many elements, even if it does.

Comment: Why would you suggest mis-using a string?