# C++ choose overloaded constructor for a stack object by condition

Tags: c++, constructor, overloading

I want something like this:

```
if (customLocation.isEmpty())
{
    KUrl url;
}
else
{
    KUrl url(customLocation);
}
/* use url */
```

Comment: As stated this question is just a case of premature optimization, however it is of general interest

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I take it you haven't seen the initial non-edited question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason you can't do

```
KUrl url;
if (!customLocation.isEmpty())
{
    url = KUrl(customLocation);
}
/* use url */
```

or

```
KUrl url = customLocation.isEmpty() ? KUrl() : KUrl(customLocation);
```

Comment: Then there's redundant constructor call

Comment: @user447503 What do you mean by redundant, what's your concern?

Comment: @john First the default constructor is called, then the overloaded.

Comment: Yes I know that, but *why* is it a concern? The code will still work no?

Comment: @user447503 That's incredible. We are talking about milliseconds. Trust me, no-one will notice. You are worrying about the wrong things.

Comment: @user447503 BTW the second option, the one you seem to prefer also calls two constructors because it calls the copy constructor as well as one of the other constructors.

Comment: The first one won't work if KUrl is not assignable. The second one won't work if KUrl is not copy-constructable.

Comment: @snak I need to check that

Comment: @snak a copy constructor isn't used to init a variable from a different type

Comment: Sure, but in the second code, it constructs an object with one of the constructors and then copy-constructs the final object with it.

You can test this by making the copy constructor private.

Comment: There are occasions this won't work, or you might not want to do it this way but I think it counts as the most usual solution. This is why I phrased it as a question.

Comment: Stupid gcc. It doesn't really use the copy constructor, but complains if it's private

Comment: According to the specification, all compilers must check whether it can access a copy constructor even though calling it can be optimized out.

Answer (score 1):

The usual C++ constructs intentionally create a very tight coupling between allocation and initialization. Thus, ordinarily you would need to use dynamic allocation to be able to dynamically specify the constructor to use. And dynamic allocation is probably some orders of magnitude more inefficient than the slight overhead that you're trying to avoid…

However, with C++11 you *can* use aligned storage and placement new.

The catch is that the `KUrl` class will most likely use dynamic allocation internally, and then all that the optimization accomplishes is to waste programmer's time: both your time initially, and the time of anyone later maintaining the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have no copy of `KUrl` being done

```
boost::optional<KUrl> ourl;
if(customLocation.isEmpty()) {
  ourl = boost::in_place();
} else {
  ourl = boost::in_place(customLocation);
}

KUrl &url = *ourl;
```

Fun aside, I would recommend Jacks solutions (if it works with your type) :)

Comment: to avoid dependency on Boost, just use a `std::vector` with `emplace_back`, and just as the above apparently relies on Boost code not doing dynamic allocation, one can then rely on the vector small buffer optimization (hopefully)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf vector [may not do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190950/may-stdvector-make-use-of-small-buffer-optimization) small buffer optimization. boost::optional documents that it does the small buffer optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why this won't work?

```
KUrl url;
if (!customLocation.isEmpty())
    url = customLocation;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
KUrl url;

if (!cusomLocation.isEmpty())
{
    url = KUrl( customLocation );
}
```