# Are move semantics guaranteed by the standard?

Tags: c++, move

I think I understand the gist of move-semantics in general but am wondering, whether the C++ standard actually guarantees move-semantics for std-types like `std::vector`. For instance is the following snippet guaranteed to produce `check = true` (if the used compiler/std-lib is standard-compliant)?

```
std::vector<int> myVec;
int *myPtr = myVec.data();
std::vector<int> otherVec = std::move(myVec);
int *otherPtr = otherVec.data();

bool check = myPtr == otherPtr;
```

In other words: When moving a a `std::vector`, does the standard guarantee that I will actually perform a move and not a copy after all (e.g. because the used std-lib hasn't implemented a move-constructor for `std::vector`)?

Comment: No, this is not guaranteed. `vector` is free to employ small object optimisation techniques, which preclude actual moving (but only for very small arrays so this is OK). In essence, if data is small enough, it can be stored in the vector itself, rather than allocated on the heap.

Comment: Neither [general container requirements](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/container.requirements.general), [move semantics](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy) or [vector details](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/vector) seem to contain such a guarantee. Would a vector implementation that does a plain copy when asked to move be compliant? Probably yes.

Comment: Alright, thank you. If you'd turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. have a read of _"...After container move construction (overload (8)), references, pointers, and iterators (other than the end iterator) to other remain valid, but refer to elements that are now in *this. ..."_ constructor (8) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector .  Continues with a Standard reference and a LWG reference.

Comment: @RichardCritten the guarantee seems to be that the elements will still exist somewhere. The question is: would a vector-that-does-copy-on-move violate the standard's wording?

Comment: @RichardCritten Hmm I don't see how the referenced portion of the standard can possibly guarantee what is claimed by cppreference.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. AFAIK, `std::vector` may not implement _small object optimization_, since, for instance, swapping the content of two vectors may not invalidate iterators. Relevant: [May std::vector make use of small buffer optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8190950/580083).

Comment: @DanielLangr yes, it seems the requirements for `swap` do prevent SOO for `vector`s.

Comment: But `std::string` for instance can do that, so there is no guarantee for it.

Comment: Highlighting the LWG link from above [Moving containers should (usually) be required to preserve iterators](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2321).

Comment: Since C++11, `std::vector` has been guaranteed to have a move constructor (with tweaks to the requirement in C++17 and C++20).   There aren't specific requirements on how that constructor is implemented (so it is not required to *actually* perform a move).  Since C++17, the move constructor is `noexcept` which means it would be somewhat more difficult to implement it in a way that doesn't involve a move (e.g. it would be hard to implement that constructor so it does a copy, since copying contents of a vector potentially throws).

Comment: @Peter _"There aren't specific requirements on how that constructor is implemented (so it is not required to actually perform a move)."_ — I don't agree, see [tab.container.alloc.req](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general#tab:container.alloc.req), or my answer. The same requirement is in the C++11 standard as well.

Comment: @DanielLangr - I see your point, but I'm not convinced since the meaning of "same" strikes me as ambiguous in this context (and not well specified in the section you link to).   For example, does "same elements" means "each of the set of elements compare equal" or "the set of elements occupies the same memory" or something else?

Comment: @Peter I believe "same element" means "same object", that is, the object in the same storage. Objects _comparing-equal_ have the same _content_. But I agree that this is likely not well defined.

Comment: @DanielLangr  I got that, and I'm not suggesting your interpretation is unreasonable.   But I've seen too many reasonable interpretations tied into messy knots by language lawyers at play and/or shot down by what an implementation does (based, presumably, on the interpretation by one or more members of the vendor's development team).   And my interpretation can be said to have the same concern!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is guaranteed for *allocator-aware containers* by the following requirement from [[tab.container.alloc.req]](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general#tab:container.alloc.req):

> `X(rv)`
> `X u(rv);`
> *Postconditions:* `u` has the **same elements** as `rv` had before this construction;...

Note the words "*same elements*", not "*elements with the same content*". For instance, after

```
std::vector<int> otherVec = std::move(myVec);
```

first element of `otherVec` must therefore be the very same element/object that was the first element of `myVec` before this move-construction.