# Benefits of vector<char> over string?

Tags: c++, string, stl, vector

This question is related to, but not quite the same as, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1556229/541686).

Are there any benefits to using `std::vector<char>` instead of `std::string` to hold arbitrary binary data, **aside** from readability-related issues?

i.e. Are there any tasks which are easier/more efficient/better to perform with a vector compared to a string?

Comment: In C++03 std::string the contiguity of its data was debatable.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Since there isn't any implementation (that I know of) that is discontiguous, I'd be willing to assume it's contiguous for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Yes, `vector<char>` indeed *does* have more capabilities over `string`.

Unlike `string`, `vector<char>` **is guaranteed to preserve** iterators, references, etc. during a `swap` operation. See: **[May `std::vector` make use of small buffer optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190950/may-stdvector-make-use-of-small-buffer-optimization)**

Answer (score 27):

Aside from readability (which should not be underestimated) I can think of a couple of minor performance/memory issues with using `std::string` over `std::vector`:

- Some modern `std::string` implementations use the [small string optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178281/small-string-optimization-for-vector). If you are storing data that's larger than the `string`'s internal buffer, it becomes a pessimization, reducing the efficiency of copying, moving, and `swap`<sup>1</sup> and increasing the `sizeof()` for no benefit.
- An efficient `std::string` implementation will always allocate at least 1 more byte than the current size for storing a terminating null (not doing so requires extra logic in `operator[]` to cope with `str[size()]`).

I should stress that both of these issues are very minor; the performance cost of them will more than likely be lost in the background noise. But you did ask.

---

<sup>1</sup>Those operations require branching on `size()` if the small string optimization is being used, whereas they don't in a good `std::vector` implementation.

Comment: Very interesting point about small strings, though I'm not yet convinced it's a disadvantage. :) Still, a great answer, thanks! +1

Comment: Where did you get the figures that tell that most implementations use small strings? It seems to me that libstdc++ does not use it, and in almost every project I have been involved to in the last decade, I have been using libstdc++ ...

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I've changed it to 'some'.

Comment: many time you need to pass in null-terminated string to legacy APIs. string has ([`string::c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)) but vector does not. This why you need the extra space also.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond readability, and ensuring another maintainer does not confuse the purpose of the `std::string`, there is not a lot of difference in function. You could of course consider char*/malloc as well, if efficiency is the only consideration.

One potential issue I can think of:

`std::string` defaults to storing `<char>`. If you later needed to handle another type (e.g. unsigned short) you might need to either:

- Create your own typedef `std::basic_string<unsigned short>` (which moves you away from normal `std::string` handling)
- Tentatively apply some reinterpret_cast logic in a setter.

With a vector you could simply change the container to a `std::vector<unsigned short>`.

Comment: Could you expand on the last part? What is the disadvantage of using `std::basic_string<unsigned short>` compared to `std::vector<unsigned short>`?

Comment: One disadvantage is that it might not compile.  :-)  `std::char_traits<unsigned short>` is not required by the standard.

Comment: @Mehrdad your issues would be mainly portability to other platforms and compatibility with other libraries. You are no longer using a traditional std::string, since the standard defines only `char` and `wchar_t` as valid char_traits. Using something else could lead to undefined behaviour if you run a string operation on the contents.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers mention, a vector could be marginally faster since it guarantees contiguous memory, even for small sizes, and doesn't add an extra null byte at the end. However, it is a lot simpler (code-wise) to concatenate two strings than it is to concatenate two vectors:

Using `vector`:

```
vector<char> a, b;
// ...
vector<char> c;
c.insert(c.end(), a.begin(), a.end());
c.insert(c.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
```

Using `string`:

```
string a, b;
// ...
string c = a + b;
```

Comment: The question asks for benefits of `vector<char>` over `string`, not the other way around... weird to see you just quote other answers on that aspect and then post your own response for the reverse direction

Comment: Hmm, perhaps this would be better suited for a different question. The reason for my answer was that this was the first result on Google for "vector<char> versus string" so I thought I'd add an answer bringing up something not mentioned.

Comment: Oh I see. Yeah it's unfortunate, since I already had a laundry list of why I'd use `string` over `vector<char>`, so that's specifically not what the question I needed answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only benefit you would gain from doing that would the ease of incrementing over the `std::vector` of characters, but even that can be done with an `std::string`.

You have to remember that even though `std::string` seems like an object, it can be accessed like an array, so even accessing specific parts of a string can be done without the use of a `std::vector`

Answer (score 0):

Ideally one would use `vector<unsigned char>` to store arbitrary binary data - but I think you already knew this - as you referred to the old question.

Other than that, using vector would definitely be more memory efficient, as string would add a terminating Nul character. Performance might also improve as the allocation mechanism is different for both - vectors guarantee contiguous memory!

Besides that, using a string would not be correct, as callers/users might inadvertently invoking some of the string methods, which could be a disaster.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on the last paragraph? What is the 'disaster'?

Comment: Consider an example: you have binary data which has multiple nul characters. If a user calls .length(), he would get some answer - which will in all probability be wrong, and he will never be alerted to the fact that it is binary data and not a string.

Comment: Why is that wrong? It seems like you're saying it would work correctly, except that it might be unreadable (i.e. misleading). That's fine, but that wasn't the point of my question -- I specifically said issues *except* readability.

Comment: @go4sri: Calling `length()` on a string with nul characters should give you the correct length. The problems arise when users start using `c_str()` and then wonder why their strings are truncated.

Comment: @Mehrdad - I do not think this comes under readability, but if you are not concerned with this kind of error, then you can skip it.