# Difference between passing array, fixed-sized array and base address of array as a function parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am confused about which syntax to use if I want to pass an array of known or unknown size as a function parameter.

Suppose I have these variants for the purpose:

```
void func1(char* str) {
    //print str
}

void func2(char str[]) {
    //print str
}

void func3(char str[10]) {
    //print str
}
```

What are the pros and cons of using each one of these?

Comment: C or C++? Pick one.

Comment: What difference does it make whether it's c or c++?

Comment: In C you can do a 4th case `void func (size_t size, char str[size])`, which might be preferable in some situations. Not possible in C++ though.

Comment: I agree that it shouldn't have both tags because C and C++ are two independent languages.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

All these variants are the same. C just lets you use alternative spellings but even the last variant explicitly annotated with an array size decays to a normal pointer.

That is, even with the last implementation you could call the function with an array of *any* size:

```
void func3(char str[10]) { }

func("test"); // Works.
func("let's try something longer"); // Not a single f*ck given.
```

Needless to say this should *not* be used: it might give the user a false sense of security (“oh, this function only accepts an array of length 10 so I don’t need to check the length myself”).

As Henrik said, the correct way *in C++* is to use a strongly typed buffer. Depending on your use-case and the actual *meaning* of the parameter, this could either be a string type (e.g. `std::string`<sup>1</sup> or `std::string_view`), a byte buffer (`std::vector<char>`<sup>1</sup> or an iterator-delimited range) or a fixed-width range or slice (`std::array<char, N>`, `std::span<char, N>`).

---

<sup>1</sup> usually as a (`const`) reference

Comment: This bit me when I tried to use boost::begin() on a function with sized array as parameter. Doesn't work. Was just pointer.. meh.

Comment: @Macke If that’s still relevant have a look at Morwenn’s answer, you *can* pass fixed-sized arrays to a function, albeit only by reference (but that should never be a problem).

Comment: might be useful to cite the standard: C99 standard 6.7.5.3, para. 7, "A declaration of a parameter as "array of type" shall be adjusted to "qualified pointer to type" ..."

Comment: Why is using `std::string` the *correct* way? It is no more correct or less correct that using pointers. There is a difference between *typical/standard* and *correct*.

Comment: @ThomasEding The only relevant difference is in terms of complexity, efficiency, and how easy it is to make mistakes. In all those regards `std::string` wins (in terms of efficiency this needs to be prefixed by “often but not always”). Using `char*` for strings is (almost) never appropriate in C++.

Comment: `std::string` loses. Incurring a heap allocation just to pass a string is bad practice. I suggest `std::string_view`, an equivalent struct of your choosing, or simply `func(char *str, size_t len)`.

Comment: @pmttavara We're talking about non string literal situations here. Otherwise by all means use a `char const*` (or pass an array by reference, i.e. `char (&arr)[N]`, where `N` is a non type template argument). In most other situations you either incur no allocation or the cost is negligible. Working on stack allocated `char` buffers is very rarely a good idea.

Comment: In cases that allocate, the cost is very non-negligible. Even ignoring the overhead of allocating, you fragment the heap, which is terrible. Templating on string length is bad, since the duplicate code bloats the binary, thrashes the icache in debug mode, and overworks (or even defeats) the optimizer in release mode. Lastly, using references as in `const std::string &` adds another pointer indirection which fosters cache misses and extra instructions (at least in debug mode, where cycles are the most precious). I *highly* suggest a string view structure passed by value.

Comment: @pmttavara I’m not sure where you’re getting these ideas. In fact, by all means use a string view or an equivalent type (especially since `string_view` isn’t yet widely supported). But you are seriously overestimating the negative impact of allocations in common scenarios. Your comment is redefining premature optimisation.

Comment: @pmttavara I’m not sure where you’re getting these ideas. In fact, by all means use a string view or an equivalent type (especially since `string_view` isn’t yet widely supported). But you are seriously overestimating the negative impact of allocations in common scenarios. Your comment is practically redefining premature optimisation.

Comment: Ignoring those issues is to deny the facts, which you do at your peril. Knowing what is and is not slow at the beginning of a project becomes indispensable once you begin refining the program into high-quality software that runs fast.

Comment: I'm wondering that nobody recommends C++ new std::array class here. If i want to pass a fixed-array, i would always prefer std::array<char>. If you need to pass it by reference, use "const std::array<char>&". This is imo much more consistent in C++ world. (Of course, string with its "small string optimization" or string_view is also a good option. Depends on the code + requirements).

Comment: @ruuns `std::array` works well for smallish buffers, but it’s not often convenient to use with strings since you can’t construct them from string literals “on the fly” (i.e. as a temporary inside an expression, or in an initialiser without repeating the literal). There are also precious little cases where you’d *need* to pass a char buffer of hard-coded size to a function. I can remember *one* case where I needed this, and I explicitly needed to support passing string literals, so I instead passed a C-style char array by const reference.

Comment: Is there a way to rewrite this function such that an overflow would be caught by the compiler?

Comment: @RickyGonce You could pass an array by reference (e.g. `func3(char const (&x)[10])`), but this only works for arrays that have *exactly* the right size. And is the size of the array really relevant? Why not take a strongly-typed fixed- or variable-sized buffer/string instead (`std::span`/`std::string_view`/…)? That’s almost always the more appropriate strategy.

Answer (score 27):

Note that in C++, if the length of the array is known at compile time (for example if you passed a string literal), you can actually get its size:

```
template<unsigned int N>
void func(const char(&str)[N])
{
    // Whatever...
}

int main()
{
    func("test"); // Works, N is 5
}
```

Comment: This will make a (tweaked) copy of `func` machine code for each new length of the literal passed.

Comment: @Ruslan True, yet I would expect any compiler to inline that at even the lowest optimization level.

Comment: Depends on the size of `// Whatever...`.

Comment: @Ruslan Oh right, I was just thinking of a function to get the size of an array and forgot the scope of the question was broader :/

Answer (score 12):

In C++, use `void func4(const std::string& str)`.

Comment: Or `void func4( std::vector<char> const& str )`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358879/benefits-of-vectorchar-over-string

Answer (score 12):

These are all functionally identical. When you pass an array to a function in C, the array gets implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element of the array. Hence, these three functions will print the same output (that is, the size of a pointer to `char`).

```
void func1(char* str) {
    printf("sizeof str: %zu\n", sizeof str);
}

void func2(char str[]) {
    printf("sizeof str: %zu\n", sizeof str);
}

void func3(char str[10]) {
    printf("sizeof str: %zu\n", sizeof str);
}
```

This conversion only applies to the first dimension of an array. A `char[42][13]` gets converted to a `char (*)[13]`, *not* a `char **`.

```
void func4(char (*str_array)[13]) {
    printf("sizeof str_array: %zu\n"
           "sizeof str_array[0]: %zu\n", sizeof str_array, sizeof str_array[0]);
}
```

`char (*)[13]` is the type of `str_array`. It's how you write "a pointer to an array of 13 `char`s". This could have also been written as `void func4(char str_array[42][13]) { ... }`, though the 42 is functionally meaningless as you can see by experimenting, passing arrays of different sizes into `func4`.

In C99 and C11 (but not C89 or C++), you can pass a pointer to an array of varying size into a function, by passing it's size along with it, and including the size identifier in the `[square brackets]`. For example:

```
void func5(size_t size, char (*str_array)[size]) {
    printf("sizeof str_array: %zu\n"
           "sizeof str_array[0]: %zu\n", sizeof str_array, sizeof str_array[0]);
}
```

This declares a pointer to an array of *size* `char`s. Note that you must dereference the *pointer* before you can access the array. In the example above, `sizeof str_array[0]` evaluates to the size of the array, not the size of the first element. As an example, to access the 11th element, use `(*str_array)[11]` or `str_array[0][11]`.

Answer (score 2):

In C, the first two definitions are equivalent.The third one is essentially same but it gives an idea about the size of the   array.

If printing `str` is your intent, then you can safely use any of them.Essentially all three of the functions are passed a parameter of type `char*`,just what `printf()` needs to print a string.And lest you don't know, despite what it may seem, all parameter passing in C is done in `pass-by-value` mode.

**Edit:** Seems like I'll have to be very rigorous in my choice of words on SO henceforth.Well,in the third case it gives no idea about the size of the array **to the function** to which it is passed as eventually it is reduced to type `char*` just as in the first two cases.I meant to say it kinda tells the human reading it that the array's size is 10.Also,it is not wrong/illegal in C.But for the program,doing it is as good as useless.It gives no idea whatsoever about the array size to the function it is passed to.Mr.Downvoter, thanks for pointing out that casual attitude and negligence is not tolerated on SO.

Comment: It gives a _bad_ idea about the size of the array.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I would never use the third syntax in any case.Just pointless to use that.

Answer (score 1):

In a one dimensional array they are all treated the same by the compiler. However for a two or more dimensional array, (e.g. `myArray[10][10]`), it is useful as it can be used to determine the row/column length of an array.

Comment: No, the third function does *not* pass an array of a fixed size. This would imply that there *is* a difference between those functions but there really is none. The type of all three functions is the same. If you want to provide a hint as to the expected array size, use a comment or documentation, that makes it clear that the size isn’t checked by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

To add-on, describing in points.

1) As everyone told it is same.

2) Arrays are decayed into pointers when they are passed in the function arguments.

3) Fundamental problem could be finding the size of a array in the function. For that we can use  macro like.

```
   #define noOfElements(v) sizeof(v)/sizeof(0[v])

   int arr[100]
   myfunction ( arr, noOfElements(arr))
```

either  0[v] or v[0] can be used in the macro, where the first is used to avoid user defined data type passed in to noOfElements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It should be v[0] in the macro you defined there.

Comment: v[0], can be written as 0[v], actually the conversion happens like this *(v+0) and *(0+v) respectively.

Comment: If you are using a macro, even better to define a macro to give you the `arr` pointer and size where you only have to write `arr` once (to avoid copy and paste errors). For example, `#define ARRAY_WITH_SIZE(x) x,sizeof(x)`. Then you can call `myfunction(ARRAY_WITH_SIZE(arr));` - You could also define `ARRAY_WITH_LENGTH` by using the same concept you used above.