# Does specifying size of array in parameter do anything?

Tags: c++

Does specifying size of array in parameter have any effect? For example.

```
void SetIDs(int IDs[22] );
```

versus

```
void SetIDs (int IDs[] );
```

Does it do nothing?

Comment: It misleads, that's an effect. If you want a specific size of array, pass it by reference.

Comment: This has been answered, but is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144535/difference-between-passing-array-fixed-sized-array-and-base-address-of-array-as

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you pass by value, an array type specifier in a parameter is always adjusted to a pointer.

```
void SetIDs (int IDs[22] );

void SetIDs (int IDs[] );

void SetIDs (int *IDs );
```

all produce the same code. Even `sizeof IDs` inside SetIDs will only return the size of a pointer as if IDs was declared as `int *IDs`.

The array size becomes relevant when you pass by reference or have a multidimensional array:

```
void SetIDs (int (&IDs)[22] );
```

This SetIDs will only accept (references to) arrays of int with size 22.

```
void SetIDs (int IDs[22][42] );
// equivalent to
void SetIDs (int (*IDs)[42]);
```

This SetIDs will accept pointers to (or an array of) an array of int with size 42.

Comment: What about program safety?  Would the compiler prevent you from passing an int[16] to a function using int[22]?  I like having the compiler find errors for me, as it's easier and faster than for me to try and find these issues (passing wrong sized arrays) during runtime.

Comment: No, not when passing by value. The array parameter (respectively the first dimension of a multidimensional array parameter)  will behave exactly as if it was declared as a pointer, without any warnings or compiler errors. Some compilers like clang will warn e.g. if you use `sizeof` inside the function on an array parameter, but there are no warnings when calling the function with `int[16]` etc.