# C++: How to pass array into an instance of a class and get the sizeof() it?

Tags: c++

I want to pass an array into an instance of a class to be used within it. However, I can't get sizeof() the array. I get the warning "Sizeof on array function parameter will return size of 'float *' instead of 'float []'. "

```
int main() {
float info[]={1.0f,2.3f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,67.8f};
Store test(info);
test.showArrayContents();
{
```

Class I want to pass array to

```
class Store{
float array[]; 
public:
Store(float temp[]){
    std::cout<<"\n"<<sizeof(temp); //can't get sizeof 
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        array[i]=temp[i];
    };
}
void showArrayContents(){
   for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
       std::cout<<array[i];
    }
 }
};
```

How can I fix to get sizeof() correctly?

EDIT: I'm not trying to find how many elements are in the array but the amount of memory it takes up, which should be 40 bytes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding length of array inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590226/finding-length-of-array-inside-a-function) Different language, same problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C sizeof a passed array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493281/c-sizeof-a-passed-array)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16148073/4944425 There probably are other dupes around.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with c style code ... but C++ does this differently.  For instance, consider declaring your float array using std:;array ... the object will have a method 'size' which reports the number of elements.  I prefer std::vector, which also has a method 'size'.

Comment: Please note that your code doesn't allocate any memory to store `array` elements. Save yourself some trouble and use a `std::vector` (or `std::array`, if the size is a compile time constant).

Comment: Despite the way it's written, `float temp[]` is a **pointer** to `float`. There's no way to get the size of the array that it points at, because it doesn't have to point at an element of an array.

Comment: The code screams to me "use `std::vector`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a *static* C-style array it is possible to infer its size using [the expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/492538/8769985)

```
sizeof(info) / sizeof(*info)
```

This is also commonly implemented via a macro [`ARRAY_SIZE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57537491/8769985). Beware however that in the above code there is no check that the actual array is a static one.

Conversely, for a dynamically allocated C-style array, there is no possibility to infer its size, since the variable itself is nothing but a pointer.

In the class constructor, even if you knew the size of the array (for instance by passing the size as parameter), or if you assume that only a static array is used (and you employ the code above to infer its size), your code has a serious bug here:

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
    array[i]=temp[i];
};
```

You are copying the elements of `temp` into `array`, but did you reserve memory for that? Again, `array` is merely a pointer to `float`, and if you do not explicitly allocate memory, in the above code you are writing into a part of memory which does not pertain to `array`. Hence you have UB.

If you know at compile time the size of the array, the right type to use is [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).
For instance

```
std::array<float, 10> info = {1.0f,2.3f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,67.8f};
```

And then you can pass it to the class with something like

```
class Store{
std::array<float, 10> array;
public:
Store(std::array<float, 10> temp) : array{temp} { }

...
```

With a `std::array` you can always know its size with [std::array::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/size).

Comment: `info` is an array of 10 `float`. The compiler infers the number of elements from the initializer, which has 10 elements. Try looking at `sizeof(info)/sizeof(*info)` to see that. You're on the right track, though: `float temp[]` as an argument defines `temp` as a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to pass an array into an instance of a class to be used within it.

Ok, there are several ways to do that, I'll show you some of those  later.

> However, I can't get `sizeof()` the array.

You can't get it *inside* the function, after the array decayed to a pointer.

```cpp
Store(float temp[]){
//          ^^^^^^    This is a pointer to float, not an array
}
```

Other than explicitly passing the size as a function argument, you could pass a reference to an array, using a template parameter to store the size ([1](https://godbolt.org/z/M4jbEa1T3)).

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Store
{
    std::vector<float> values_;
public:
    template< std::size_t N >
    Store(float const (&temp)[N]) : values_{temp, temp + N}
    {}//              ^^^^^^^^^^
 
    void showArrayContents() const noexcept
    {
        for(auto i : values_)
        {
            std::cout << ' ' << i;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    float info[]={1.0f,2.3f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,67.8f};
    
    Store test(info);
    test.showArrayContents();
}
```

Get rid of the source array and use a `std::initializer_list` ([2](https://godbolt.org/z/Gv3Kr7vax)).

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

class Store
{
    std::vector<float> values_; 
public:
    Store(std::initializer_list<float> src) : values_{src}
    {}
 
    //...
};

int main()
{
    Store test{1.0f,2.3f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,67.8f};
    test.showArrayContents();
}
```

If the size never has to change during the lifetime of `Store`, you can use a `std::array` ([3](https://godbolt.org/z/PMMzGP4oM)).

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template< class T, std::size_t N >
class Store
{
    std::array<T, N> values_; 
public:
    Store(T const (&src)[N]) 
    {
        std::copy(src, src + N, values_.begin());
    }
 
    //...
};

//deduction guide
template<class T, std::size_t N> Store( T (&src)[N] ) -> Store<T, N>;

int main()
{
    float info[]={1.0f,2.3f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,67.8f};
    
    Store test(info);
    test.showArrayContents();
}
```

You can also avoid the source array and initialize the class with a constructor accepting a template parameter pack ([4](https://godbolt.org/z/rsW3WWGf9)).

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template< class T, std::size_t N >
class Store
{
    std::array<T, N> values_; 
public:
    template< class... Args >
    Store(Args... args) : values_{args...}
    {}
 
    //...
};

//deduction guide
template< class... Args >
Store(Args &&... ) -> Store<std::common_type_t<Args...>, sizeof...(Args)>;

int main()
{
    Store test{1.0f,2.3f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,67.8f};
    test.showArrayContents();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I fix to get sizeof() correctly?

Option #1: you could pass in the size of the array.

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::size;
using std::size_t;

namespace {

class Store {
    size_t array_size;
    float* array;
public:
    ~Store() {
        delete[] array;
    }
    Store(float temp[], size_t temp_size) : array_size{temp_size} {
        cout << "temp_size:" << temp_size << "\n";
        array = new float[temp_size];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < temp_size; ++i) {
            array[i] = temp[i];
        }
    }
    Store(Store const&) = delete;
    auto operator=(Store const&) -> Store& = delete;
    void showArrayContents() {
        auto sep = "";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < array_size; ++i) {
            cout << sep << array[i];
            sep = " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
};

} // anon

int main() {
    float info[] = { 1.0f, 2.3f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 67.8f };
    Store test(info, size(info));
    test.showArrayContents();
}
```

Option #2: you could use a template constructor for the array.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::size_t;

namespace {

class Store {
    size_t array_size;
    float* array;
public:
    ~Store() {
        delete[] array;
    }
    template <size_t N>
    Store(float (&temp)[N]) : array_size{N} {
        cout << "N:" << N << "\n";
        array = new float[N];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            array[i] = temp[i];
        }
    }
    Store(Store const&) = delete;
    auto operator=(Store const&) -> Store& = delete;
    void showArrayContents() {
        auto sep = "";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < array_size; ++i) {
            cout << sep << array[i];
            sep = " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
};

} // anon

int main() {
    float info[] = { 1.0f, 2.3f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 67.8f };
    Store test(info);
    test.showArrayContents();
}
```

Option #3 (best option): you could use `std::vector`.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using std::cout;
using std::move;
using std::ostream;
using std::size_t;
using std::vector;

namespace {

class Store {
    vector<float> array;
public:
    Store(vector<float> temp) : array{move(temp)} {
        cout << "temp size:" << temp.size() << "\n";
    }
    void showArrayContents(ostream& out) const {
        auto sep = "";
        for (auto&& e : array) {
            out << sep << e;
            sep = " ";
        }
        out << "\n";
    }
};

} // anon

int main() {
    auto info = vector<float>{ 1.0f, 2.3f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 67.8f };
    auto test = Store{info};
    test.showArrayContents(cout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the array length as an argument also, when you pass an array to function what you actually pass is a pointer to start location of array i.e. `float*` in your case, so when you ask for size it simply gives you size of pointer .
So either pass the size explicitly, or use `std::vector` which will give you the length.

other than that if class `Store` is the owner of array, why not define it inside class?