# Address of an array different with the address of the first element?

Tags: c++

As I know address of array `a` is the address of first element of this array.

```
void func(int a[])
{
    cout << "address in func: " << &a << endl;;
    cout << "GT: " << &a[0] << endl;
}

int main ()
{
    int a[] = {0,1,2,3};
    cout << "address in main: " << &a << endl;
    cout << "address in main a[0]: " << &a[0] << endl;

    func(a);
}
```

Output:

```
address in main: 0x7ffef67d6790
address in main a[0]: 0x7ffef67d6790
address in func: 0x7ffef67d6778
GT: 0x7ffef67d6790
```

Why address of array `a` in func() difference with address of `a[0]`?

Comment: You've passed a copy of the pointer to the function. Thus the copy and the original pointer are separate entities and so have different addresses.

Comment: `&a` is the address of the local variable `a` in `func`, not the address of the local variable `a` in `main`. The original address is `std::cout << a`. It will be a bit more clear if you declare `void func(int b[])` or `void func(int* b)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between passing array, fixed-sized array and base address of array as a function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144535/difference-between-passing-array-fixed-sized-array-and-base-address-of-array-as)

Comment: `void func(int a[])` is actually `void func(int* a)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why address of array a in func() difference with address of a[0]?

Because you're calling the function `func()` passing `a` **by value**. This means the `a` inside the function `func()` is actually a copy of the original *decayed* pointer that you're passing to `func()` from `main()`. And since **they're different variables, they have different addresses**. Thus by writing `cout << &a;` you're printing the address of this separate **local variable** named `a`.

If you want to print the original address, you should write inside `func()`:

```
void func(int a[])
{
//---------------------------------v---------->removed the &
    cout << "address in func: " << a << endl;;
    cout << "GT: " << &a[0] << endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/dgyYvxY1o)

```
address in main: 0x7ffcfb0a4320
address in main a[0]: 0x7ffcfb0a4320
address in func: 0x7ffcfb0a4320
GT: 0x7ffcfb0a4320
```

Answer (score 0):

As it has been explained in the comments, you're not passing the "same" variable to your function.
When you're calling your function, it makes a local copy within it of your array of int.

In order not to waste memory, and let's say you upgrade your program and now, you're not passing to your function an array of int but a std::vector which is quite big, we have in C++ arguments passed by references (myType & myVar).

This is the same than passing an argument by pointers in C.
Passing something by reference actually creates an ALIAS to the variable passed. So you'd now have 2 ways to act on the variable : the variable itself in your main program, and the alias in your function.

Obviously, if you do not want to modify it in the function, you can pass it by const reference (const myType & myVar) which is the same than in C with const *.

Answer (score 0):

It is a fallacy inherited from C that

```
void func(int a[])
```

would pass an array to the function.

While `int a[]` looks like an array you can't actually pass an array to a function. An array always decays to a pointer and the pointer is actually what you pass to the function. So the above is equivalent to writing

```
void func(int *a)
```

and maybe now you can see why `&a`, the address of the local pointer, and `&a[0]` the address of the first element of the array are different.