# In C if I use an array as parameter of an function array size has no meaning because of arrayname as pointer

Tags: arrays, c, size

as far as I know

```
int func(int arr[5]) {
    printf("Test");
}
```

the size of the array in the square braces (e.g. 5) has no meaning because of arr is just the pointer to the first element of the array, i.e. it is the same like

```
int func(int *arr) {
    printf("Test");
}
```

or

```
int func(int arr[]) {
    printf("Test");
}
```

But why is it possible to write a number like 5 in the square braces if the number itself has no meaning?

Comment: “Why?” questions risk being closed as off-topic because they usually cannot be answered without speculation. But your understanding of the matter is correct, and it isn’t obvious that the ability to syntactically include a number here is a good design. In fact, in hindsight it probably isn’t ([as I’ve said before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16144616/1968)).

Comment: Maybe I overlook something. Is there a scenario where I should use something like int arr[5] instead of int arr[] or int *arr if arr is used as a parameter in a function?

Comment: There are different opinions on this but if you ask me: no. In C, you should *never* specify an array bound size on an argument, since it is not checked, and thus misleading. It is no better than a non-normative comment, and the comment at least makes clear that this is not actually checked. A *competent* programmer of course knows that the array bound is not checked, but unfortunately misunderstandings of this syntax are extremely widespread, and lead to usage errors.

Comment: @KonradRudolph "since it is not checked"  ...except when it _is_ checked. It may not be checked by the _compiler_ but a competent programmer may use additional static analysis tools beyond that. Furthermore, there are several situations where it could be made checked by the compiler as well. I posted an answer with some examples.

Comment: @knowledge "... if the number itself has no meaning?" is a false supposition.  The `number` does have meaning, yet perhaps not constrained as one thinks.

Answer (score 6):

It is true that the array notation gets adjusted ("decays") into a pointer to the first element, making all your 3 examples equivalent. The language was designed this way to make array use in expressions compatible with functions, since when an array is used in most expressions, it also "decays" into a pointer to the first element.

The size does kind of have a meaning though:

- It is self-documenting code.
- It helps diagnostic tools (compilers and/or static analyzers) to find array parameter mismatches.

---

You can increase the type safety a little bit by declaring the parameter `int arr[static 5]`, where `static` means pass *at least* 5 items and not a null pointer. "Decay" still happens, but modern compilers may give diagnostic messages:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int arr[static 5]) 
{
  printf("Test");
}

int main(void)
{
  int a[5];
  func(a); // ok

  int* b;
  func(b); // accepted

  int c[4];
  func(c); // not ok

  func(NULL); // not ok
}
```

---

You could also declare the parameter as a pointer to array `int (*arr)[5]`. This increases type safety even further, since it means *must pass an array of exactly 5 int*. But makes the function more cumbersome to work with since you'll have to de-reference the parameter as `(*arr)[i]` when using it. Array arguments have to get passed as `func(&a)`.

Comment: What you call “self-documenting code” I call *lying* code. Using the `static` syntax is notably different because it is actually (potentially?) enforced. But as long as the other syntax is not *widely* enforced, it will cause complacency and false reliance on it. — And this is not a theoretical issue, I have seen this in practice: people are *shocked* when they realise that their code was incorrect, and that the compiler did not enforce the invariant they had assumed and accidentally violated.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The problem you describe is not really related to this particular feature, but to people putting way too much trust in the compiler, compared to other means of identifying bugs. Such as static analysis, dynamic analysis, peer review, debugging, unit testing etc etc. The compiler/linker has exactly 2 duties: inspect the source code to see if it is following the syntax & constraints of the C language, and then generate some sensible output in the form of an executable for the given system. It's not there to hold the programmers hand as they learn C, it never did.

Comment: I fundamentally disagree that people putting trust into compilers is the issue. People *should* (be able to) put trust in compilers, and a core contribution of better languages (than C) is that people *can* trust compilers. The issue here is also not (primarily) compiler quality, since the compilers correctly represent C semantics. The issue is that the C semantics are bad, and are prone to misunderstanding: people misunderstand this syntax. — Static analysis tools are great, but they can only do so much to fix language mis-features. At some point we need to avoid those mis-features.

Comment: As well as being more cumbersome, `int (*arr)[5]` makes it look like the function is expecting to operate on a 2-D array.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It doesn't matter which language that is used - if compiler diagnostics is the_only_ means to discover problems in the code, the whole development procedure is fundamentally broken. That's a staff and manager competence problem not really related to programming. Also C's weakness of being an old and flawed language is also its strength: all those flaws are well-known, documented and easy to avoid, by using coding standards and safe subsets. Compare this with for example C++ where no single person knows exactly how many cases of poorly-defined behavior the language contains.

Comment: @IanAbbott IMO that would rather have been written as `int arr[n][5]`. But 2D arrays is another story.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question without a satisfying (or at least authoritative) answer.  It's just one of the warts of the language.  It's like asking why you can write pointer declarations as either `T *p` or `T* p`; it's nothing to do with pointers specifically, it's just an accident of the language design.

I suspect that syntactically it was just plain easier to treat array declarators the same in both function parameter and regular declarations, rather than have different syntax rules for function parameters.  And given the limitations Ritchie and Thompson and Kernighan were operating under, that makes sense.  We have the benefit of 50 years' worth of hindsight, but at the time I doubt any of them thought C would become as widely used as it has.

This is one of those areas where C expects you to know what you're doing; you're expected to know how array expressions behave, and you're expected to know how function parameters behave and write your code accordingly.