# Does a std::string need to be filled to have a size diffrent of zero?

Tags: c++, string

I am facing a situation where I would like to give a `std::string` a size, but without filling it with characters.

Unfortunatly, no constructor allow to do that, and the only function to set the size of `std::string`, called `resize(size_t size, char n)` also require a character to fill the `std::string`..

Is there any way to do this?

It's probably going to be a no, but I would like to be sure I didn't miss anything, or if they are any alternative means to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to resize it without filling it with characters? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: you can https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize

Comment: @UnholySheep I am reading data from a socket with `boost::asio`, using `async_read()`. It takes a buffer as parameter, created with a string, and returns the value only when the buffer is full or the connexion has been lost. As the buffer has a size of 0, `async_read` considers it is full and don't fill it.

Comment: oh you're right @wtom, I missed that. Write it as an anwser and I will accept it

Comment: A buffer sounds like you want a `std::vector<char>` (or `std::vector<std::byte>` if you are using C++17), not a `std::string`

Comment: @UnholySheep, no it's a `boost::asio::buffer` and the constructor I am using takes a `std::string` as parameter.

Comment: @souki. No, it's not exactly what you want. "The first version initializes new characters to CharT()". I would prefer vector<char>

Comment: @UnholySheep, well actually you might be right, since there are tons of constructors, and some of them take `std::vector<>` as parameters. One question thought, why is it better than `std::string` in my case ?

Comment: there seems to also be a constructor which takes a `string` and a size (or max size), maybe you can use this and pass an empty string

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve

Comment: @suoki. I would say in general terms std::string is designed to be treated as container for zero terminated C string, not memory buffer. In semantics, memory allocation policies, terminating '\0', etc.

Comment: Isn't `std::vector` slower than `std::string` though?

Comment: Slower how? How did you compare their performance?

Comment: Read it in some SO anwser, can't find it back though. But it's just a question.

Comment: highly unlikely. especially if you reuse memory that is allocated once =) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358879/benefits-of-vectorchar-over-string

Comment: @wtom good to know, thanks!